# Can I execute a python statement from a terminal?

Tags: debian, python

I'd like to simply execute a Python command without having to write a script or enter the interpreter. Is there a way that I could run something like:

```
python --execute "pow(12.31351,2)"
```

And have it simply print the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `-c` arguments,like `python -c "print 123"`,see `python --help`

```
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
     -c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)
```

Comment: Right, just needs a `print` statement to dump to `stdout`, gotcha.